# .Net 4 Garbage Collection

Tags: java, .net, c#-4.0, garbage-collection

I tried to read up garbage collection algorithms in Java and in .Net recently. So far I found out that java uses Mark and Sweep as algorithm within its collectors.

Is .Net using Mark and sweep as well on all the generations?

How did Microsoft moved from concurrent G0, G1 collector, running SERIALLY with G@ collector, to a sth called BACKGROUND GC, where everything is parallel?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Have you read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx.aspx? It sounds like it will explain in greater detail than any single answer here.

Comment: Most JVMs, including the popular ones, *don't* just use mark-and-sweep!

Answer (score 1):

.NET GC is a mark and sweep garbage collector. 
Background GC means that you can perform Gen2 GCs while your application is running. If your application is allocation intensive, and the background GC can't free up enough space for the new allocation, the BGC collector is stopped, and a stop-the-world collector is used to do a full Gen2 GC (which could result in compacting the heap, or expanding it)

Hope this helps